# jquery clarification regarding preventDefault

Tags: jquery, function, preventdefault

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

"If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered."

"default action" means redirecting people from a different page when they click a hyperlink, as far as i observed in sample code.

is there any other use for this function?

how does it interact with forms?

Comment: Good question. I normally use "return false;" which does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `preventDefault` prevents the default action of the event from being triggered. The default action of the event depends on the type of event, and the event target.

For example, if `preventDefault` was used in a click event handler for a checkbox, the checkbox would not become checked upon click. If it was used in a `keydown` event handler for an text input, the pressed key would not be written to the input value. If it was used in a `submit` event handler for a form, it would prevent the form from submitting.

Basically, it stops any event from performing the action it would perform by default.

Answer (score 2):

`preventDefault` will prevent the default event occuring, so, for example, if we linked the following code to a form -

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` call will prevent the form being submitted as that is the default event that would normally occur on a form submit.

Answer (score 1):

It prevents the default action of the element, whatever that default action might be.

In the case of forms and inputs, in response to a click or such, it would prevent checking a radio-button or checkbox, it would prevent the submission of the form (or whatever action was specified) when clicking the `submit` button.

Answer (score 1):

`preventDefault()` prevents any default action of browser or so for the specified event.

There are many practical use of `preventDefault()`, I have summarized a few for you. You will also find the answer to your question about forms within this.

It prevents:

- Submitting form while clicking submit button
- Submitting form while pressing enter
- Sometimes it can also prevent scrolling
- Keypress actions also.
- Right click browser menu
- Opening new tabs while clicking middle button on link
- Opening links while clicking left button, as you mentioned,

And there are many